# "website may be down" error when i try sudo rosdep init

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-kinetic, sudo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used pip to install `rosinstall` on my mac (`sudo pip install -U rosinstall`).

This worked but every time I try to initiate it, the website doesn't connect. I tried disabling my firewall--still didn't work. When I go to the website at `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list`, it doesn't seem to be down. I have macOS Catalina and my software is up to date.

Does anyone know how to get around this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345503/%22website-may-be-down%22-error-when-i-try-sudo-rosdep-init/) by [mmcd2523](https://answers.ros.org/users/52180/mmcd2523/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-03-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-02**:
Without seeing a verbatim copy-paste of the command *and* the error message, we cannot help you.

Additionally: the question title mentions `rosdep`, but the question text only states you've installed "`rosinstall`". Which of the two is it?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-02**:
Did you try again some time later?

The website does occasionally go down for a couple hours here and there.

**Comment by [mmcd2523](https://answers.ros.org/users/52180/mmcd2523/) on 2020-03-02**:
Yes, I did try again, and on multiple days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most common reason for this failure is that your ssl negotiations are failing. This can be caused by a lack of certificates on your system or your clock is out of tolerance for the ssl negotiations.

There's a lot of other questions related to this: https://www.google.com/search?q=website+may+be+down+rosdep

A few I found quickly are: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/9721 and https://answers.ros.org/question/316260/rosdep-init-cannot-download-default-sources/ Please try to look in to some of these other threads and edit your question with the outputs of the debugging that you do.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mab0189](https://answers.ros.org/users/69650/mab0189/) on 2021-03-08**:
@tfoote Thank you very much for your answer. I also run into this error and setting the correct time solved it for me. [Here is a good overview of methods how you can set your time](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/set-time-date-timezone-ntp-linux-shell-gnome-command-line.html)